# HTML th and td tag with nested ngFor loops (with dynamic column headers & values)

Tags: html, typescript, html-table, ngfor

I am trying to create HTML table with dynamic tr and td.
I have added nested loops in the HTML itself , dynamic column headers(th) are working fine but values are not getting added in correct td.

Here is a data I have :

```
 "finalResult": [
        {
            "tableNamee": "Table_1",
            "colCategories": [
                {
                    "columnnnn": "User",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "60"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "columnnnn": "Header1",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "460"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "columnnnn": "Amount",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "100"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "50"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tableNamee": "Table_2",
            "colCategories": [
                {
                    "columnnnn": "User",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "07"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "columnnnn": "Amount",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "70"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "columnnnn": "User1",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "57"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "columnnnn": "Column",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "80"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "columnnnn": "Column2",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

And below is the html code for it :

```
  <div *ngFor="let j of finalResult; index as i" class="">
    <div class=""> <span title="{{j.tableNamee}}">Table Name : {{j.tableNamee}} </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="">
                    <th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let k of j.colCategories">
                        {{k.columnnnn}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let k of j.colCategories">
                    <tr class="">
                        <ng-container>
                            <div *ngFor="let m of k.values">
                                <td class="">
                                    <div class=""> <span title="{{m.value}}"> {{m.value}} </span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container>
                    </tr>
                </ng-container>
            </tbody>
    
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

There is no any specific ts code for this. I just manipulated data in above format and trying to apply loops in HTML itself.  Am I doing anything wrong?

**this is desired output :**
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVvZA.png)

**and this is current output I am getting :**
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSsI6.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup looks weird in that your `<tr>` contains a `<div>` which wraps the `<td>`s. And I think that is what's causing your problem.

I have not tried this but may you can try changing your `<table>` markup to this:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="">
                <th class="" scope="col" *ngFor="let k of j.colCategories">
                    {{k.columnnnn}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="" *ngFor="let k of j.colCategories">
                <td class="" *ngFor="let m of k.values">
                    <div class="">
                        <span title="{{m.value}}"> {{m.value}} </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```